# Passing a StoredProcedure with Parameters to a function in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do i pass a stored procedure with parameters to a function.

I actually have a function to insert data into database..
im looking for a way where i could pass the SP with parameters to that
insert function so as to reuse the insert data code.

Answer (score 1):

Put the call to the stored procedure in a method and call this method from anywhere you want to call it. Pass parameters (strings, ints, doubles, ...) to this method and put these values in the stored procedure's parameters.

This way you keep all the SP code in one place.

```
public class CustomerProvider
{
    public int UpdateCustomer(int id, string name, string address)
    {
        using(connection = new
            SqlConnection("Server=localhost;DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var command = new SQLCommand("csp_updatecustomer", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", id));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", name));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerAddress", address));
            var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, since im a newbie in c# it would help if you could give me some sample code on how to do this..

Comment: I added an example. Note I didn't add sufficient exception handling. But this should give you an idea.